# How to Append Text in Cells instead of Overwriting it with Keyboard in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut in Excel, to append a cells value **without overriding** it (like it does by double klicking on the cell with the mouse)

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Are you looking for alternative to CTRL + V?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can edit a cell by selecting it and pressing `F2`.